# Issuing with calling methods in Inherited class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, methods

This "Code A" is the code of my base class and i am extending this class to another class "Code B". The problem is when i run my app my application has stopped. Is there any problem with my Base class or i not call them properly? Activity is registered in manifest file.

**Code A**

```
public class PrepaidBase extends Activity {

PrepaidBase pb = new PrepaidBase();

private String number = "";

public void alertDialogShow(Context context, String title, String message, String _number) {

    this.number = _number;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            call();
        }
    });


    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


}

public void call()
{
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(number)));
    try
    {
        startActivity(in);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
public class PrepaidLBO extends PrepaidBase {

Button chobeesButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chobeesghantay);

   chobeesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chobeesButton);

   pb.alertDialogShow(PrepaidLBO.this, "Some Test" , "Text Here too" , "*1234#");

   chobeesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           call();
        }
   });

}
```

**Logcat**

```
06-24 18:34:07.281    2533-2533/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-24 18:34:10.168    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 94(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 1.833ms total 114.739ms
06-24 18:34:10.835    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-24 18:34:14.157    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 39.850ms
06-24 18:34:14.295    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:15.103    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:15.472    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:18.337    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:18.931    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:19.856    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:21.059    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.443ms
06-24 18:34:21.406    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 157 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:24.141    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:26.998    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:27.414    2533-2533/adnan.com.ufone I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 18:34:28.707    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 47.201ms
06-24 18:34:29.101    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 31.696ms
06-24 18:34:29.607    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 37.610ms
06-24 18:34:30.220    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 147.585ms
06-24 18:34:30.360    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6086(146KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 51.143ms total 352.611ms
06-24 18:34:30.366    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.379ms
06-24 18:34:30.632    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 57.711ms
06-24 18:34:30.645    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 14.495ms
06-24 18:34:30.736    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 236(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 95.529ms total 346.798ms
06-24 18:34:30.790    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 54.155ms
06-24 18:34:31.194    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 119.068ms
06-24 18:34:31.388    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1581(37KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 80.648ms total 581.160ms
06-24 18:34:31.397    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.587ms
06-24 18:34:33.209    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 592.155ms
06-24 18:34:33.368    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 26.443ms
06-24 18:34:33.386    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6587(103KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 12MB/12MB, paused 111.437ms total 1.029s
06-24 18:34:33.638    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 365(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 13MB/13MB, paused 66.483ms total 230.992ms
06-24 18:34:34.259    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 178.489ms
06-24 18:34:34.609    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 23.285ms
06-24 18:34:34.627    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4630(107KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(4MB) LOS objects, 27% free, 10MB/14MB, paused 121.820ms total 959.586ms
06-24 18:34:35.477    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 392.420ms
06-24 18:34:35.637    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.761ms
06-24 18:34:35.661    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6057(94KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 14MB/14MB, paused 127.324ms total 713.914ms
06-24 18:34:35.662    2533-2546/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 310.554ms for cause HeapTrim
06-24 18:34:36.544    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 418.091ms
06-24 18:34:36.637    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 51.426ms
06-24 18:34:36.657    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.696ms
06-24 18:34:36.844    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2386(37KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 15MB/19MB, paused 141.802ms total 1.153s
06-24 18:34:37.938    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 348.103ms
06-24 18:34:38.227    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.882ms
06-24 18:34:38.258    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8373(130KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 20MB/20MB, paused 182.373ms total 951.554ms
06-24 18:34:38.266    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.610ms
06-24 18:34:39.299    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 706.498ms
06-24 18:34:39.383    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 45.575ms
06-24 18:34:39.407    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 17.370ms
06-24 18:34:39.699    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 69.589ms
06-24 18:34:39.746    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 994(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 21MB/25MB, paused 239.301ms total 1.413s
06-24 18:34:41.051    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 453.236ms
06-24 18:34:41.115    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.914ms
06-24 18:34:41.142    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.221ms
06-24 18:34:41.382    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7876(123KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 25MB/25MB, paused 220.215ms total 1.145s
06-24 18:34:42.597    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 997.392ms
06-24 18:34:42.684    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 35.773ms
06-24 18:34:42.712    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 23.099ms
06-24 18:34:42.963    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 44.938ms
06-24 18:34:42.996    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 648(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 25MB/29MB, paused 229.056ms total 1.552s
06-24 18:34:44.302    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 686.164ms
06-24 18:34:44.618    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 19.549ms
06-24 18:34:44.657    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6491(101KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 29MB/29MB, paused 242.421ms total 1.111s
06-24 18:34:44.697    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.579ms
06-24 18:34:46.091    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 982.963ms
06-24 18:34:46.187    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 48.409ms
06-24 18:34:46.217    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 30.455ms
06-24 18:34:46.521    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 53.534ms
06-24 18:34:46.557    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 493(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 29MB/33MB, paused 279.881ms total 1.793s
06-24 18:34:46.558    2533-2546/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 177.448ms for cause HeapTrim
06-24 18:34:46.565    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.621ms
06-24 18:34:46.617    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.539ms
06-24 18:34:48.156    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 527.372ms
06-24 18:34:48.227    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 19.215ms
06-24 18:34:48.262    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 23.554ms
06-24 18:34:48.573    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7983(124KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 34MB/34MB, paused 299.130ms total 1.363s
06-24 18:34:50.275    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 1.148s
06-24 18:34:50.383    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 55.210ms
06-24 18:34:50.420    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 30.946ms
06-24 18:34:50.987    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 55.924ms
06-24 18:34:51.027    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 736(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 34MB/38MB, paused 540.864ms total 2.293s
06-24 18:34:52.411    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 788.050ms
06-24 18:34:52.967    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 18.129ms
06-24 18:34:53.016    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6533(102KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 38MB/38MB, paused 460.383ms total 1.518s
06-24 18:34:53.022    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.227ms
06-24 18:34:54.877    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 1.750s
06-24 18:34:54.994    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 56.245ms
06-24 18:34:55.034    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 34.575ms
06-24 18:34:55.600    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 60.212ms
06-24 18:34:55.646    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 523(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 39MB/43MB, paused 540.285ms total 2.500s
06-24 18:34:55.707    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.558ms
06-24 18:34:57.529    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 882.265ms
06-24 18:34:57.916    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.107ms
06-24 18:34:57.967    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6570(102KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 42MB/43MB, paused 330.003ms total 1.484s
06-24 18:34:58.076    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 18.763ms
06-24 18:34:58.166    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.498ms
06-24 18:35:00.368    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 1.725s
06-24 18:35:00.509    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 80.845ms
06-24 18:35:00.554    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 34.853ms
06-24 18:35:01.107    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 129.755ms
06-24 18:35:01.207    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 396(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 43MB/47MB, paused 457.546ms total 2.876s
06-24 18:35:01.213    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.128ms
06-24 18:35:01.268    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.916ms
06-24 18:35:02.922    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 771.276ms
06-24 18:35:03.348    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.384ms
06-24 18:35:03.427    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6529(102KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 46MB/47MB, paused 362.529ms total 1.599s
06-24 18:35:03.436    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.090ms
06-24 18:35:05.916    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 2.370s
06-24 18:35:06.058    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 69.562ms
06-24 18:35:06.104    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 35.235ms
06-24 18:35:06.626    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 118.373ms
06-24 18:35:06.717    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 403(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 47MB/51MB, paused 437.964ms total 3.091s
06-24 18:35:06.727    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.203ms
06-24 18:35:06.817    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.111ms
06-24 18:35:08.997    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 1.331s
06-24 18:35:09.487    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.644ms
06-24 18:35:09.586    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6093(95KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 50MB/51MB, paused 413.239ms total 2.087s
06-24 18:35:09.588    2533-2546/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 1.165s for cause HeapTrim
06-24 18:35:09.608    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.341ms
06-24 18:35:09.719    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.034ms
06-24 18:35:12.316    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 2.375s
06-24 18:35:12.541    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 133.257ms
06-24 18:35:12.625    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 77.153ms
06-24 18:35:13.123    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 73.703ms
06-24 18:35:13.196    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 396(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 50MB/54MB, paused 500.092ms total 3.198s
06-24 18:35:13.206    2533-2547/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.346ms
06-24 18:35:13.316    2533-2540/adnan.com.ufone W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 17.881ms
06-24 18:35:13.934    2533-2539/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Thread[2,tid=2539,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-24 18:35:13.935    2533-2539/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ Mutator lock exclusive owner tid: 2540
06-24 18:35:13.935    2533-2539/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ ThreadList lock owner tid: 2540
06-24 18:35:13.935    2533-2539/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ ClassLinker classes lock owner tid: 0
06-24 18:35:13.935    2533-2539/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ ClassLinker dex lock owner tid: 0
06-24 18:35:13.935    2533-2539/adnan.com.ufone I/art﹕ [ 06-24 18:35:13.971  2533: 2539 W/art      ]
    Suspending all threads took: 35.743ms
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Are both activities registered on manifest, or only B?

Comment: both activities are registered in manifest file

Comment: Please check my logcat where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also implement BASE class like this

```
public class PrepaidBase extends Activity {

AlertDialog.Builder builder;

private String number = "";
private String packageName;
private String price;
private String title;

public PrepaidBase()
{}

public void setPackageInformation(String name, String price, String number, String title)
{
    this.number = number;
    this.packageName = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.title = title;
}

public void activatePackage()
{

    try
    {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(PrepaidBase.this)
                .setTitle(PrepaidBase.this.title)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to activate " + PrepaidBase.this.packageName + " in RS: " + PrepaidBase.this.price)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(PrepaidBase.this.number)));
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                //.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and you other CHILD class which inherit from your BASE

```
public class PrepaidLBO extends PrepaidBase  implements View.OnClickListener {


Button chobeesButton;
public PrepaidLBO()
{
    setPackageInformation("Package Name", "Your Price", "*123#", "Your Title");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chobeesghantay);
    chobeesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chobeesButton);
    chobeesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    activatePackage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recursivly creating a lot of instances.
Your problem is this line *PrepaidBase pb = new PrepaidBase();* , which is inside *PrepaidBase* activity.
Meaning every time an instance of PrepaidBase is created, it creates another instance of itself, until you reach the memory limit, and GC kicks in.

Comment: what i do now? without creating instance it does not allow me to call aleartDialogShow() and call() method of base class

Comment: PrepaidLBO extends PrepaidBase, meaning that it **has** aleartDialogShow method, you can directly call it.

Comment: i am new in programming can you please tell me the code of PrepaidLBO ?

Comment: Just remove *PrepaidBase pb = new PrepaidBase();* line , and change *pb.alertDialogShow(....);*  to *alertDialogShow(...);*

Comment: it is working but alertDialogShow() method does not call while clicking on activate button?

Comment: What activate button? What error? You should make another question if the issue about which you asked and this one are unrelated