# How do i call "Alert Dialog" in inherited class

Tags: android

I have a alert dialog which is declared in PrepaidBase which have two methods alertDialogShow() and call(). That call() method call when click on "Yes" button of alert dialog and alertDialogShow() method call on Activate button of layout.

**PrepaidBase**

```
public class PrepaidBase extends Activity {


private String number = "";

public void alertDialogShow(Context context, String title, String message, String _number) {

    this.number = _number;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            call();
        }
    });


    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


}

public void call()
{
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(number)));
    try
    {
        startActivity(in);
        alertDialogShow(this, "Some Test", "Text Here too", "*1234#");
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now this class inherit from PrepaidBase class

```
public class PrepaidLBO extends PrepaidBase {

Button chobeesButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chobeesghantay);

   chobeesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chobeesButton);


    chobeesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //alertDialogShow(PrepaidLBO.this, "Some Test", "Text Here too", "*1234#");
            call();
        }
    });


}
```

Issue is

I want to call alertDialogMethod() on clicking on chobeesButton. and Call() method is called when click on positive button of alert dialog.

Comment: `alertDialogShow(PrepaidLBO.this, "Some Test", "Text Here too", "*1234#");` Should work. What's the issue ?

Comment: orb `super.call()` @Blackbelt ?

Comment: bor where? @codeMagic

Comment: @Blackbelt `chobeesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` but maybe I'm unclear on the issue. It happens...

Comment: @codeMagic he didn't override it on `PrepaidLBO`, so it not necessary. Do you think he is showing some partial code ?

Comment: @Blackbelt possibly. Or he isn't explaining exactly what is/isn't happening. Errors, etc...

Comment: imo NPE on the button, @codeMagic

Comment: Follow this link to implement onclicklistener https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/

Comment: Maybe. Or it has something to do with extending Activity and having a method that requires a context @Blackbelt . Too many questions

Comment: fair enough. `this` is crying. @codeMagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both questions are almost same i already provided you the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027811/issuing-with-calling-methods-in-inherited-class)